# Using non-native CUDA structures in texture memory

Tags: cuda, textures

Is it possible to use an extended version of the `CUDA` native type `float4` in texture memory? For example, I have several things that I would like to group using a structure in one texture:

```
struct {
   float x;
   float y;
   float z;
   float w;
   float t;
   float m;
};
```

Which extends the definition of `float4` by `t` and `m`.

I Googled around but didn't see anything addressing this particular issue. Thanks for the help!

Comment: No that is not possible. The texture fetching functions e.g `tex1Dfetch`, `tex2D`, `tex3D` etc... have not been implemented for custom data types.

Comment: Bummer. Alright, thanks @sgar91

Comment: @sgar91: you should post that as the answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, texture fetching for textures of user defined data types is not supported by CUDA. The texture fetching functions like `tex1Dfetch`, `tex2D`, `tex3D` etc are implemented only for textures of some specific types.